# I'm trying to forecast an ETS model using data from tsibbledata in R but I'm getting the error message seen at the bottom of the code below

Tags: numeric, forecast

```
ItalyExp <- global_economy %>% 
filter(Country == "Italy")
ItalyExp$Exports <- as.numeric(as.character(ItalyExp$Exports))

ItalyExp %>% autoplot(Exports) + labs(title = "Italian Exports")

etsANNit <- ItalyExp %>%
model(ETS(Exports ~ error("A") + trend("N") + season("N")))

etsANNit

fc <- etsANNit %>%
forecast(h = 10)
```

This gives the error message:

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors